# Extracting just year from date and time in Python

Tags: python, extract

I want to single out all the data from 2020 in a dataset. The date is formatted like this: 06/10/2011 06:47:44 PM

I tried this out just to see if I could single out the data and count it, but it didn't work:

```
count = 0 
d2020 = data311['Created Date'][6][-13]
for d in d2020:
    if d == '2020':
        count += 1

print(count)
```

It runs but doesn't return anything, if that makes sense. I've tried other ways, but the only difference is that it'll return 0, which is obviously incorrect.

I'm not actually trying to count the data from 2020, I just want to use only 2020 data to be able to plot it on a map.

This is the dataset: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Social-Services/311-Noise-Complaints/p5f6-bkga

Comment: Maybe you should add what your data is. -just a suggestion

Comment: @TimothyChen is asking what format is the data911?  It is a pandas dataframe, is it a dictionary etc.  Also is the 'Created data' a datetime, or a string or some other item?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example is a good guide to asking a good question.

Answer (score 1):

If your dates are always formatted like `06/10/2011 06:47:44 PM` as given in your question, you can certainly use a fixed slice of the string as you have attempted, except that instead of:

```
data911['Created Date'][6][-13]
```

you should use the slice opeartor `:`:

```
data911['Created Date'][6:-12]
```

Or to do it the more elegant way, you can use `datetime.datetime.strptime` to parse it into a `datetime` object and then get its `year` attribute:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime(data911['Created Date'], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p').year
```

Comment: Why are you using .. as slice operator?

Comment: Oops brain malfunction. Corrected then. Thanks.

Comment: I tried using your second suggestion, but I keep getting this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/throwaway.py", line 11, in <module>
    datetime.strptime(data311['Created Date'], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p').year
TypeError: string indices must be integers` And I've tried converting it to `int` using `int(data311['Created Date'])` and `data311['Created Date'].astype(int)` but none of those work

Answer (score 1):

If df is your dataframe and 'Created Date' is your column, you can select the rows of 2020 by this (the key is the usage of .str in filtering/boolean indexing):

```
newdf=df[df['Created Date'].str[6:10]=='2020']
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get results with this by itself, but I doesn't work with the rest of my code. I'll have to play around with it to see if I can get it to run all together